# TS - NodeMailer OAuth2 'auth' does not exist in type 'TransportOptions

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemailer

I have a problem. I need to make email sending function with Gmail api. In docs it tells me to make a `createTransport` function like this:

```
    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        user: "horvatlucian1@gmail.com",
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
        accessToken: accessToken,
      },
    })
```

[DOCS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dJkt.png)

But it all turns red and returns:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dJkt.png)

Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: You attached link on DOCS and Error are same screen shots.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem of type script when you tring to pass the accessToken because in google oauth2client the return type of `getAccessToken()` is https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/b0ddb7512fb9ed1e51b6874b7376d7e1f26be644/src/auth/oauth2client.ts#L331

that not supported by the types of nodemailer that should be string:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7827d853a1d623dd5345d9a11ced3e15eb5d3d8b/types/nodemailer/lib/xoauth2.d.ts#L24

by looking at the return type of the getAccessToken you can see that the token is inside that have type string so to fix that just destructure your token from the accessToken.

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    type: "OAuth2",
    user: "horvatlucian1@gmail.com",
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
    accessToken: accessToken.token,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1/

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: String("gmail") || "",
  auth: {
    type: String("OAuth2"),
    user: String(SENDER_MAIL),
    clientId: String(CLIENT_ID),
    clientSecret: String(CLIENT_SECRET),
    refreshToken: String(REFRESH_TOKEN),
    access_token: String(access_token),
  },
});
```

```
and the ERRO WITH MSG :
    [ERROR] 14:02:23 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
    server/config/sendmail.ts(25,7): error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
      The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ service: string; auth: { type: string; user: string; clientId:string; clientSecret:string; refreshToken:string; access_token:GetAccessTokenResponse; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransportOptions | Transport<unknown>'.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'service' does not exist in type 'TransportOptions | Transport<unknown>'.
```

Answer (score -1):

The accessToken required in nodemailer.createTransport is nullable

Because of that, to avoid error, you must cover the case when accessToken is null by providing an empty string or something similar to avoid null error

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                type: 'OAuth2',
                user: process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
                clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
                refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
                accessToken: accessToken.token || '',
            },
        })
```

Hopefully that help